# How to split video with MediaMetaDataRetriever

Tags: android, video, split

I am programming in Android environment, and I want to load a video file from the device, to split it into frames and process each of them with some image-processing techniques.

In order to split correctly the video into an array of frames, I am using MetaDataRetriever class, giving it in input the path of the file.

My problem is that I don't understand how to split correctly the file using the getFrameAtTime method. In particular, my code is:

```
    MediaMetaDataRetriever media = new MediaMetaDataRetriever();
    media.setDataSource(this.path);
    String durata = media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    int durata_millisec = Integer.parseInt(durata);
    durata_video_micros = durata_millisec * 1000; 
    durata_secondi = durata_millisec / 1000; 
    String bitrate = media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE);  //numero bit al secondo.

    int fps = 10;
    int numeroFrameCaptured = fps * durata_secondi;
    int i=0;
    while(i<numeroFrameCaptured){
        vettoreFrame[i] = media.getFrameAtTime();
    }
```

With a fps of 10, I should have 10 frame per second. So, in a file of 5 seconds, I should have 50 captured frames at all. How to do this? How to write correctly the while/for statement to capture all these frames with getFramesAtTime method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String durata = media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
int durata_millisec = Integer.parseInt(durata);
durata_video_micros = durata_millisec * 1000; 
durata_secondi = durata_millisec / 1000; 
String bitrate = media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE);    
int fps = 10;
int numeroFrameCaptured = fps * durata_secondi;
ArrayList<Bitmap> frames;
frames = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
Bitmap bmFrame;
MediaMetaDataRetriever media = new MediaMetaDataRetriever();
media.setDataSource(this.path);
totalFotogramas = durata_millisec/1000*fps; //video duration(micro seg)/1000s*fotogramas/s

for(int i = 0; i < totalFotogramas; i++){
bmFrame = mediaLowResolution.getFrameAtTime(100000*i , MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

frames.add(bmFrame);

```
}
```

Hope it´s useful